# Breadth first printing for tree with multiple child nodes

Tags: c++, tree, breadth-first-search

I have a tree data structure in which parent node can have any number of child nodes(>=0).(see sample_tree.jpeg) I want to create such tree. One of the possible approach thought by me is creating a linked list as shown in my_approach picture. Linked list are connected as shown. Can you help e here to write breadth first print with this structure??
Please write code in C++.
IF not possible, can u suggest suitable structure?[image]

[image: my approach]

Comment: simply , how to create a tree with multiple childs and perform print breadth first operation?

Answer (score 1):

Storing every single node in a linked-list would be a (probably) poor way to manage it as you would have to know what order you should go to next, especially if you don't add them in the order you want to pirnt them out.

A better data structure would be to create a class for each node, and give it a private variable of a vector or linked-list of its children.

Then use a different class that would manage the printing of each node, by maintaing a FIFO queue for the order to print them.

some basic pseudo-code, as it was a while ago i did this:

```
class Node {
    public:
        ...    
        void addChildren(vector<Node*>*);


    private:
       vector<Node*> _children;
};

void addChildren(vector<Node*>* queue) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < _children.size(); i++) {
        queue->push_back(_children.at(i));
    }
}
```

where the queue variable is just a vector maintained by the main function (or another class if you wanted better encapsulation) which is iterated over. The only thing you would likely have to explicitly add is the first node to the queue.

Then when printing from the queue:

```
vector<Node*> queue;

//create your nodes statically or dynamically
//populate the queue with the first node

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < queue.size(); i++) {
    //print whatever you want from the node here

    //This adds the current node's children to the end of the FIFO queue
    queue.at(i)->getChildren(queue);
}
```

that should go over all the nodes and add them in a breadth first manner.

one note, i changed linked list to vector here because it's faster when you only need to add data to the end of the container.